# Mobile App Performance : Polymer or Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, polymer, google-chrome-app

I am a web developer and I heard that Google just released the "production ready" version of **Polymer** (1.0). On the other hand, I have heard a lot about **Ionic** since 2013. I am now trying to find the best way to make a web app look native, responsive and effective as well.

*I am seeing two great ways of making web apps now :*

1. Make a responsive and material-design based Chrome Web App then turn it into a Cordova Project.
2. Start a fresh Ionic project with ready-to-use CSS components and native understanding JavaScript components

**I am not asking for everyone's opinion**.

I would like to know the **major difference of performance** (if there is one) between these two ways of developing a web app (that seem to be the most efficient for me). And if there are better ones, please let me know.

Thanks for the help :-)

Here are some informations about the tools I am talking about :

- [Polymer 1.0](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/)
- [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, I would go with Ionic, since it's has an awesome CLI, and they constantly improve already great docs. The things they're doing with additional services like [push](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-from-scratch) is just awesome. Also, one thing they said will be coming is the ability to publish through them, so you won't have to have Mac for iOS.

Also, they're working tightly with Angular 2.0 team. You mentioned Cordova - ionic CLI uses it under the hood already.

I successfully published one app with Ionic so far in both stores (iOS/Android) and am preaching the Ionic awesomeness to all my friends, so yeah I may be biased, but from my personal experience I can't recommend Ionic enough.

But then again, you should probably try both and make your own decision.

However, since I see you're a new user here, let me just give you a heads up and say that this question will be most probably closed due to the rules where questions like "what's your opinion on X or Y" get closed. Anyways, I wanted to tell you about how awesome Ionic was in my experience.